# Jdbc-Spring-Kafka id column track

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-mvc, jdbc, apache-kafka

I connected jdbc with spring and Spring with Kafka but I have problem now. I'm trying to push data from jdbc to Kafka every 800ms but I don't know how, what to track so Spring could knows "from where" (for example:

1. 800ms he got to id = 10,000,
2. 800ms he need to start from id=10,001) to start with collecting and pushing new data.

I can't use timestamp because I have in the same moment more than one row in database, also, is the **id** good represent, because he can reach its limit?

I tought to use **Periodic triggers** which are implemented in Spring but is that a good way or someone has better idea?

**EDIT**

As @TobiSH requested more infos, here they are. So, data is incoming in database all the time, every milisecond. I want to trigger App in Spring(every 800ms) so spring pulls the data, send it to kafka and afterwards compute that data in Kafka with Spark and push it to Cassandra/Hadoop but its another case. So, no, I don't want to trigger App everytime something in database is changed, I want to trigger App to collect data from database **(every 800ms)**, but *only* data he didn't collected it already.

Comment: Could you describe your problem a little bit more detailed? What should be the trigger to push something to kafka? Everytime a change was made at your mysql database? That sounds actually pretty hard. Maybe you could add your specific use case.

Comment: Here you go. Is it more clear now?

Comment: Which data should be pulled by spring? I have actually very little knowledge of spring. But I guess it's quite hard to find out what have changed. Are you sure spring can do this? I would start with a simple approach (without kafka) which just write the data to stdout. If that works the rest cant be that complicated ...